# Lightning Out show toast event handler issue

Tags: visualforce, lightning, event

I have a component that catches showToast events that are triggered by my code calling the showToast event but when I edit a record using the standard edit page the handler doesn't catch the 'Success' toast message generated by the built in functionality after saving the changes. All the code is inside of a Lightning component in a Visualforce page using Lightning Out.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning Out unfortunately doesn't support everything that's available in Lightning Experience. Some functions are dependent on the Salesforce one.app container, and that 
isn't part of Lightning out.

In the limitation section of [Lightning Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_considerations.htm) it says:

> Many important actions
>   your apps support are accomplished by firing various Lightning events.
>   But events are sort of like that tree that falls in the forest. If no
>   one’s listening, does it have an effect? In the case of many core
>   Lightning events, the “listener” is the Lightning Experience or
>   Salesforce app container, one.app. And if one.app isn’t there to
>   handle the events, they indeed have no effect. Firing those events
>   silently fails.

The documentation on the [ShowToast](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast/documentation) event says:

> This event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in
>   Lightning Experience, Salesforce app, and Lightning communities.

Combined I'd say you'll have to build your own solution. I believe Lightning is open source these days so perhaps you can include the relevant parts.